# RabbitMQ - What does it mean to declare a queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and I have a question. Here is a sample snippet that I see often in tutorials.

```
    public static void Send(string queueName, string data)
    {
        using (IConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection())
        {
            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                    durable: true,
                    exclusive: false,
                    autoDelete: false,
                    arguments: null);

                // Publish to the named queue
                channel.BasicPublish(string.Empty, queue, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am confused because the concept of declaring a queue every time you want to call the `Send` function is a bit weird to me. Does that mean it creates a new queue every time?

Some of the sample code for receiving from a queue also has a `queueDeclare` call.  Why is it needed there?

Comment: If you wish to learn more about messaging and EAI then look no further than the book _[Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Integration-Patterns-Designing-Deploying/dp/0321200683/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1532042015&sr=1-1&keywords=enterprise+integration+patterns)_.  Just about every contemporary EAI system out there is based on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it only creates the queue if it doesn't already exist:

> Declare queue, create if needed.
>
> This method creates or checks a queue. When creating a new queue the
>   client can specify various properties that control the durability of
>   the queue and its contents, and the level of sharing for the queue.

And

> Declaration and Property Equivalence
>
> Before a queue can be used it has to be declared. Declaring a queue
>   will cause it to be created if it does not already exist. The
>   declaration will have no effect if the queue does already exist and
>   its attributes are the same as those in the declaration. When the
>   existing queue attributes are not the same as those in the declaration
>   a channel-level exception with code 406 (PRECONDITION_FAILED) will be
>   raised.

References[1](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html) & [2](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html)

Comment: That helps. Thank you!

Comment: In theory, you should be able to declare the channel once and store a reference to it that can be accessed by multiple functions.  I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ enough yet to know if that's a good idea or not though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner is correct - creating a new connection and channel per-message is one of the worst RabbitMQ anti-patterns. It is literally the most inefficient way to interact with RabbitMQ. This may not matter depending on your message publish rate, however.